# How to make a date that can rollover months and years

Tags: javascript

I want to create an incremental date. I have two buttons, one increases the date by 1 and another decreases it by 1. It works well until the end of the month or year; how to make it so it rolls over and can change depending on the month, as some months don't have the same amount of days?

Here's the code I have thus far

```
var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate()+days;
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd<10) {
            dd = '0'+dd
        } 
        if(mm<10) {
            mm = '0'+mm
        } 

        today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;


$("#label").text(today);
```

`days` is a variable I'm using to add the days to the function

Comment: You can stick with numbers and do simple math, and the use the Date setter to move the date forward or back. Thus to move to the next day, just add 1 to the return value of `.getDate()` and then set it with `.setDate()`. The API automatically handles rolling over month and year boundaries.

Comment: `Date()` allways rolls over. `new Date(2018,8,34)` will result in `2018-10-04`

Comment: Or use a library like momentjs where you can easily add or subtract a day from a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the days directly to the Date, it will handle it:

```
 var today = new Date();
 today.setDate(today.getDate() + days);

 var dd =   today.getDate();
 var mm =   today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
```

Comment: yea this works , thanks ill mark this as soon as pos !

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="label">

 </div>
 <button type="button" onclick="add()" name="button">Add</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="sub()" name="button">Subtract</button>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var days = 0;
var core = function(){
  var today = new Date();
  today.setDate(today.getDate() + days);
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if(dd<10)  dd = '0'+dd
  if(mm<10) mm = '0'+mm
  $("#label").text(dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy);
};
function add(){
  days = days + 1;
  core();
}
function sub(){
  days = days - 1;
  core();
}
add();
</script>
</html>
```